# specify where to start strlen() in a char array c

Tags: c, arrays, string

Let's say that I have the following character array. I need to know if there is a way to get the length of the second string in the array. I know I could use `strlen`, but this gives me the length of the first string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     char greeting[20]={'P','H','O','N','E','\0','6','0','1','7','1','2','1','2','1','6','\0'};
int count;
count=strlen(greeting);  // this returns the length of first string which is 5
}
```

Comment: `strlen(greeting + 1 + strlen(greeting))`

Comment: `strlen(&(greeting[6]));`

Comment: First you have to remember that an array naturally decay to a pointer to the first element, then you have to remember how to use pointer arithmetic. Something else that is good to remember is that `greeting[X]` is equivalent to `*(greeting + X)`.

Comment: @pmg post that as the answer, it is. And explain why of course.

Comment: Ha! I don't really want to explain why it's a bad idea to have imbedded NULs in a string :)

Comment: @mpg:  pedantic note: a string cannot have an embedded `'\0'` other than the one null character that ends it.  A `char` array can have 0 or more embedded `'\0'` like OP's `greeting`.

Answer (score 6):

A valid string in C is null terminated

Having 2 null characters in the char array might cause lot of issues especially while using inbuilt functions.

If you really want to do this

```
strlen(greeting + 1 + strlen(greeting));
```

`strlen()` works on a null terminated strings and if you pass just `greeting` to it then the length will be calculated till the first null is encountered and length will be returned so now we need length from the character after first null so you should calculate as shown above.

Comment: It's not that bad to have the construct the OP is using if used carefuly.

Comment: @iharob I mean while using inbuilt functions like strlen() OP might not get what is expected

Comment: Oh, sure. I agree, it's just a comment.

Comment: I'm making this up, but it's not completely unreasonable to store strings like that in a file (i.e. NUL terminated). It's then not unreasonable to read them back and start trying to size them up. Beyond that (or similar) it seems like a hard work way of manipulating strings. But then again I don't really accept the C style where you have find NUL every time you take the length is really fit for purpose.

Comment: I find this a bit hard to read. I'd prefer to write the code in a more generic way, or this snippet is quickly going to get obscure (find the 3rd sub string etc).

Answer (score 1):

Simple, generic, readable way:

```
size_t  s_length [SUBSTRINGS];
const char* strp = greeting;

for(size_t i=0; i<SUBSTRINGS; i++)
{
  s_length[i] = strlen(strp);
  strp += s_length[i] + 1; // +1 to skip null termination
}
```

Comment: Btw this snippet is an obvious candidate for a function, such as `void get_strlengths (size* s_length, size_t substrings);`